# Javascript Blur background when div is block?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem with bluring the background when my menu is open. I tried writing something on my own but it's not working.

```
function backgroundBlur() {
  var menuBox = document.getElementById("mobile-menu");
  var blur = document.getElementById("body");
  if (menuBox.style.dsiplay = "block") {
    blur.style.filter = "blur(3px)";
  }
}
```

Comment: Any errors? You misspelled "display" for starters.

Comment: There's a typo on the word 'display' on this line: `if (menuBox.style.dsiplay = "block") {`

Comment: Just another things:
1. In if statement, you need to use == or === (=== is recommended but please read the differences).
2. If you don't change the reference of a variable, you can declare it as const (menuBox and blur variables).
3. You can name blur as body (cause this is the body).
4. You can declare a class in a css file that contains filter blur, and just add the class to the body (instead of adding css into js).

Comment: toggle a class.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem can be caused by three reasons:

- Typo noted by @RyanWalls
- The `backgroundBlur()` method is not called
- The `display` property of the `menuBox` is not `block`

I made a run to simulate this event:

```js
let button = document.getElementById('setBlur');
let control = false;

function backgroundBlur(control) {
  var menuBox = document.getElementById("mobile-menu");
  var blur = document.getElementById("body");
  
  if (menuBox.style.display === "block")
  {
    if(!control)
    {
      blur.style.filter = "blur(3px)";
      button.innerHTML = 'Remove Blur';
    }
    else
    {
      blur.style.filter = "blur(0px)";
      button.innerHTML = 'Add Blur';
    }
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    backgroundBlur(control);
    control = !control;
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}
#body{
  background-color: black;
}
button{
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}
.vertical-menu {
  width: 200px;
}
.vertical-menu a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.vertical-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="mobile-menu" style="display: block;">
    <div class="vertical-menu">
      <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<button id="setBlur">Add Blur</button>
```

Comment: please fix the if statement (menuBox.style.display = "block") to ===

Comment: And why is your `<button>` outside the `<body>`? OP said `#body` (an element with the ID "body"), not the actual document body. If you blur the document body everything will be blurred.

Comment: @Terry I noticed something interesting; the program doesn't work if i don't add `display: block;` style to ` <div>` tag ; this way the `menuBox.style.display` value is read as empty.

Comment: @AlonShmiel I noticed something interesting; the program doesn't work if i don't add `display: block;` style to `<div>` tag ; this way the `menuBox.style.display` value is read as empty.